# Gmail accessToken and refreshToken from Android App

Tags: android, google-oauth

I have a backend app which uses gmail access token and refresh token to access user's gmail account.

```
    TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
    tokenResponse.setAccessToken(accessToken);
    tokenResponse.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
    Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setTransport(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setTokenServerUrl(
                new GenericUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"))
            .setClientAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication("abc.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
                    "xyz"))
            .build()
            .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
```

On the frontend, I have an android App where I have access to the authorizationToken:

```
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(),SCOPES)
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName( (String)SharedPrefUtils.getValue(SharedPrefUtils.PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME,SharedPrefUtils.DATA_TYPE_STRING));
```

But how to get the accessToken and refreshToken from this to send to the backend 
app?
 Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through following:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth

Look at section :Android app obtains offline access for web back-end